# Removing intersection between instances

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I made this with geometry nodes and I was wondering if there is a way to remove some of the sphere instances which are intersecting with each other? Tried to use delete geometry but it doesn't seem to be working.[image]

[image]

Comment: Sphere intersections is actually an easy problem, so yes, it can be done…

Comment: But maybe you would want to e.g. clamp the size of the spheres so they are always there but never overlap? 

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady hey man thanks for suggesting but i want the sizes of the spheres to be randomized, just trying to figure out a way to set a minimum distance between the spheres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reasonable strategy is to use *Merge by Distance* node. Unfortunately this node moves (averages) positions (and all other attributes) of points, so you need to move them back - but after moving them back they may still overlap! Therefore you need to repeat the process a few times:

[image]

With the *Merge Still* group being:

[image]

And for completeness, Suzanne was hexagonized with:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! this is what i was looking for!

Comment: hey man, just another question! if i would like to switch the spheres to another object instead, how do i plug the value node to the object info node for that object? @MarkusvonBroady

Comment: @xander you could use a "Transform" node, and plug it to the scale of it… Just keep in mind, this solution is only exact for spheres, for any other object it will be an approximation.

Comment: alright, thank you so much once again!